# How to Build Apache calcite Excel Adaptor

Tags: java, apache-drill, apache-calcite

where i can get Excel Adaptor for Apache calcite.

```
class ExcelEnumerator<E> implements Enumerator<E> {

}
```

I'm trying to created ExcelEmumarator Class.

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing Excel adapter for Calcite. I would suggest asking on the mailing list https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/calcite-dev/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed excel adaptor for calcite

Git Repo

https://github.com/prasadnanobi/CalciteAdaptor.git